# How can i use Azure AD like AWS cognito to signup/signin users and api authentication with custom UI as i can do it in the Cognito?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, azure, amazon-cognito

I am trying to create a user authentication / login system with azure ad and i am not able to find something for the above question, please help

Comment: Look into Azure AD B2C. It is the AWS Cognito equivalent service in Azure.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are referring to an Identity service.
Azure has two main identity services: AzureAD and AzureAD B2C.

AzureAD B2C is the equivalent of AWS Cognito.

Look at the [AzureAD B2C](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/active-directory/external-identities/b2c/#features) features.

The [MSAL library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-overview) provides the tools to implement the flow of authentication in several stacks like .NET, Java, Angular, React, Python, iOS, macOS, etc.